# Creating a dictionary from a pandas data frame. on column contains sets

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary  from a column containing set like

```
d = {'col1': [{'A','B'},{'C','D'},{'A','C'},{'C'}], 'col2': [3, 4,5,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to apply something such that

```
df.apply(something)
```

I get

```
[{A:[3,5]}, {B:[3]}, {C:[4,5,7]},{D:[4]}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `melt`, `groupby` + `apply(list)`, and `to_dict`:

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.col1.tolist())
   .join(df.col2)
   .melt('col2')
   .groupby('value')['col2']
   .apply(list)
   .to_dict())
# {'A': [5, 3], 'B': [3], 'C': [7, 4, 5], 'D': [4]}
```